# Gulp copy files from all subfolders to destination and flatten one level

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a folder of components, with structure:

src/components
  component-name
    html
    js
    css

I want to copy these to dest/components, I want the files of each component to be in a separate component folder but I want the HTML/JS/CSS folder level flattened.

E.g so the end result would be:

/dest/components/my-component/(.html, .js & .css) all at this level

How can I do this with gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) to solve this kind of problems and simply pipe the matched file names as:

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');

```
var folders = ['hello/*.**'];

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src(folders, { base: '.' })
               .pipe(rename(function(path) {
                  console.log(path)
                  path.dirname = path.basename;
              }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

This is my folder structure before the transformation:

[image]

And this my folder structure after running gulp:

[image]

Comment: @mparnisari It's Atom with the file icons package